# Долго выполняется скрипт

Tags: php, битрикс, память

Я запускаю скрипт и выдается вот такая ошибка:

> Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 1073741824 bytes exhausted (tried
>   to allocate 295735506 bytes) in
>   /var/www/admin/www/online.site.ru/bitrix/modules/security/classes/general/post_filter.php
>   on line 44

увеличила `ini_set('memory_limit', '2048M');` стал долго выполняться скрипт. В какую сторону копать?

Comment: что делает скрипт? скорее всего перебирает много записей и что то с ними делает. Опишите сперва что делает скрипт.

Comment: Он импортирует элементы из промужуточной базы 1с(куда попадают значения из 1с) в битрикс.Товары и торговые предложения.

Comment: а долго это сколько? вообще окончания процесса дождались? сколько там записей?

Comment: нет... 1000000 строк в инфоблок товаров

Comment: а профилирование не пробовали делать на меньшем объеме данных? тогда бы показало что именно не так. Только было бы не плохо эту стену кода разбить на более мелкие участки, тогда и профилирование было бы точнее, и вам бы проще было изменения вносить

Comment: пробовала, быстро идет...  на 20 элементах.

Comment: "профилирование" не в том быстро или не быстро, а в том на что тратится время, и 20 элементов - это не тест, а небольшая проверка работоспособности. Берете 1 тыс. элементов и смотрите - если очень быстро (всего несколько секунд) - берете 10 тыс. и т.д. Когда скрипт начал работать несколько десятков секунд (можно пару-другую минут), тогда и смотрите на что тратилось время.

Comment: Миллион строк в инфоблок товаров -- это очень много при любых раскладах. Как вариант, что приходит в голову -- попробовать настроить так, чтобы делалась выгрузка только новых товаров.